# RecyclerView onClick result in Same activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want the feature in the image. Please check the image. 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeSjv.png)

When I click the recycle view item, I want to show the item details below the item. Please check the image and help me..Thank you

Comment: Check this link on how to expand recycler view items https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Answer (score 1):

in your adapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View listItemView = convertView;
listItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //put your code here
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: That question is about `RecyclerView` _NOT_ `ListView`. Please check the title and tags used in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you were wrong. The code contains part of the Adapter class of a ReciclerView. Read it well.

Comment: AFAIK there's no `getView()` method in RecyclerView adpter. Read the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) for RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: Sorry, RecyclerView.Adapter<YouAdapter.ViewHolder>

Answer (score 1):

The recyclerList view should contain the following :

1. View having details of the list Item in collapsed state (Example Name)
2. View having the expanded details of the list item (Example - description) - this view will set to visibility - gone by default.

In RecyclerViewAdapter - onBindViewHolder

`holder.firstview.setOnClickListener` - set the visibility of the secondview to visible

Example :

```
holder.firstView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view)
          {
            holder.secondView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
      });
```